# PostgreSQL - how to fetch rows higher then year since the date

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, date-difference

I have in the `DATE` column saved a dates. I try to get those rows, that are higher since that date about a year, two years etc.

The `year`, `two years` is a parameter from my app. Is possible to get these rows by a query or should I do that on the application layer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE the_date_column > current_date - interval '2' year
```

Just replace the 2 with your parameter value from the application.

Comment: +1 Wasn't aware of the syntax variant `interval '2' year`. I always use `interval '2 year'`. That one got away from me - too well hidden [in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: I have never used a different one and was surprised that `'2 year' ` also worked ;)